# How to redirect to particular stores when the site opens

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, store-view

My website has 2 stores

there are two different store codes for that

the first is **`us`** and the second is **`ms`**

when I enter mysite.com then it redirects to `mysite.com/us`

but I want to change it to **`mysite.com/ms`**

How to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: let me know what you have tried to achieve this? it will helpful to give solutions for moderators.

Comment: Do you have store views or stores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database Search for table 'mag_core_config_data'

In that table, there is one field **scope_id** which is set according to your websites.

The site is redirected according to this store id. you need to set proper id for your website.

I have set lower id to mysite.com/ms than mysite.com/us.

It worked for me. you can also try if you are facing the same problem.

Comment: by using htaccess, also can be redirected.